# Removing blank rows or rows with half blank and half null in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe as

```
id    name    address 
 1    xyz      nc
     null          
 ..blank line....
 3    pqr     stw
```

I need to remove row 2 and 3 from the dataframe and need following output

```
id    name    address 
 1    xyz      nc
 3    pqr     stw
```

I have tried using

```
df1.filter(($"id" =!= "") && ($"id".isNotNull)).filter(($"name" =!= "") && ($"name".isNotNull))
```

But here i need to do it for every single column by iterating column over column,is there a way where i can do it on an entire row level not by iterating over the columns.

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730081/how-to-iterate-each-column-in-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala) question to iterate over all columns in a dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Iterate each column in a Dataframe in Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730081/how-to-iterate-each-column-in-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala)

Comment: @Jeremy i can iterate over the columns...i was looking for a transformation which does removing on row basis not iterating on individual columns.

Comment: Is there a better way to denote `..blank line....`? Is it `null, null, null`? Your question is slightly unclear because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterEmpty = udf((cols: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => cols.map(_.equals("")).contains(true))

df.na.fill("").filter(filterEmpty(array("id", "name", "address")) =!= true).show(false)
```

where `filterEmpty` is a `udf` function which returns `true` if any of the columns contains an empty value.

`na.fill("")` replaces all `null` values to empty value in the dataframe.

and `filter` function filters out the unnecessary rows.

I hope the answer is helpful